# Powershell get Azure VM name from private IP

Tags: powershell, azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine, devops

I want to get azure VM name from IP address, I tried following to get NIC name from IP and find to which VM that NIC is attached.

`Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface | ForEach { $Interface = $_.Name; $IPs = $_ | Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig | Select PrivateIPAddress; Write-Host $Interface $IPs.PrivateIPAddress }`

Is there a better way to get VM name directly using VM private ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a better way to get VM name directly using VM private ?

Do you mean use VM's private IP address to get the VM's name?
If I understand it correctly, we can use this PowerShell to get the VM's name:

```
PS C:> get-azurermvm

ResourceGroupName  Name Location      VmSize OsType     NIC ProvisioningState
-----------------  ---- --------      ------ ------     --- -----------------
RGNAME            jason   eastus Standard_A1  Linux jason66         Succeeded

PS C:\> $a = ((Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface | ?{$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress -eq '10.0.0.4'}).VirtualMachine).ID
PS C:\> $vmname = ($a -split '/') | select -Last 1
PS C:\> $vmname
jason
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Ansible using the Metadata service:

```
---
- name: Test Playbook
  hosts: 10.1.0.4
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Call VM metadata service to get compute fields.
    uri:
      url: http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute?api-version=2017-08-01
      return_content: yes
      headers:
        Metadata: true
    register: vm_metadata

  - set_fact:
      vm_name: "{{ vm_metadata.json.name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ vm_metadata.json.resourceGroupName }}"

  - debug: 
      msg: Adding disk to <RG={{ resource_group }}> <VM={{ vm_name }}>
```

Result is:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test-vm.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com] => {
    "msg": "Adding disk to <RG=test-rg> <VM=test-vm>"
```

See API details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service